# bad request after curl post request

Tags: php, curl

I would like to work with this api: https://www.etermin.net/api/index.html#api-Calendar-Get

For this I API part I have the following code:

```
$cURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.etermin.net/api/calendar?ublickey='.$publicKey.'&salt='.$salt.'&signature='.$encodedSignature.'');
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
```

This code works fine !

Now I would like to create a appointment with this api: https://www.etermin.net/api/index.html#api-Appointment-Create

Now I need a post request solution and I tried this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.etermin.net/api/appointment");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'publickey'     =>  $publicKey,
    'salt'          =>  $salt,
    'signature'     =>  $encodedSignature,
    'start'         =>  '2021-04-28%2018:00',
    'end'           =>  '2021-04-28%2019:00',
    'calendarid'    =>  '1234',
    'firstname'     =>  'Max',
    'lastname'      =>  'Mustermann'
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);


echo '<pre>';
var_dump($server_output);
echo '</pre>';
```

I get the response:

```
string(11) "Bad Request"
```

I need help! :(

Comment: Remove the http_build_query() call and leave the data as array. Using a POST request will convert it automatically.

Comment: I updated my code without http_build_query() - same result

Comment: Referring to the linked docs, (at least) the time format is wrong. `Format: yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM e.g. 2017-10-24 18:00`. Replace `%20` with a space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (encrypt headers to header, not postfields):

```
$publicKey = 'YOUR PUBLIC KEY';
$privateKey = 'YOUR PRIVATE KEY';
$salt = mt_rand();
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $salt, $privateKey, true);
$encodedSignature = base64_encode($signature);

$url = "https://www.etermin.net/api/appointment"
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt(
            $ch, 
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
            array(
                 'publickey:'.$publicKey,
                 'salt:'.$salt,
                 'signature:'.$encodedSignature 
            )
);

curl_setopt(
            $ch, 
            CURLOPT_POST, 
            1
);

curl_setopt(
            $ch,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            array(
                 'start'         =>  '2021-04-28%2018:00',
                 'end'           =>  '2021-04-28%2019:00',
                 'calendarid'    =>  '1234',
                 'firstname'     =>  'Max',
                 'lastname'      =>  'Mustermann'
            )
);

curl_setopt(
            $ch, 
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 
            true
);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```